# add attributes to a networkx network from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a .gml file like as the following:

```
graph [
  directed 1
  node [
    id 0
    label "5B5F2C071D12AF13219DF5EBE05132AF"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "9FB3B96B6D5E16C9DD564AA3E84F1954"
  ]
  node [
    id 2
    label "B3299B0E587D7275E3E4D530E9EECF50"
  ]
  node [
    id 3
    label "6432F1DF21BA38368D9A165C739EEBB3"
  ]
  node [
    id 4
    label "85D5C50A6D882CA8E4BB00BCA3574417"
  ]
  node [
    id 5
    label "0D8583F810B9720A8032BB939F12B3FF"
  ]
  node [
    id 6
    label "6C10A9E9F325CAA3CCB7F9A0D6983D2A"
  ]
  node [
    id 7
    label "B0C50ED1DEC9E06E4C64E7419DDC4B09"
  ]
]
```

I read this file like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

G = nx.read_gml(path)
list(G.nodes(data=True))
```

and I have a pandas dataframe like as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'USER': ['5B5F2C071D12AF13219DF5EBE05132AF', '9FB3B96B6D5E16C9DD564AA3E84F1954',
                           'B3299B0E587D7275E3E4D530E9EECF50', '6432F1DF21BA38368D9A165C739EEBB3',
                           '85D5C50A6D882CA8E4BB00BCA3574417', '85D5C50A6D882CA8E4BB00BCA3574417'],
                 'CLASSE': [3,3,2,2,1,1]})
df
```

I need to merge between the two data sets so that the `CLASSE` attribute of the dataframe presented above is added to the network, making the network look like the following demonstration:

```
graph [
  directed 1
  node [
    id 0
    label "5B5F2C071D12AF13219DF5EBE05132AF"
    CLASSE 3
  ]
...others nodes
```

I need to do this because I want to filter the network ober the `CLASSE` attribute. Can anyone help?